# Transições de cor com fade em uma palavra

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

tenho um código que está fazendo transições de cor, tem como deixar um fade nessa transição, ou seja, para ela nao ficar mudando tão "seca", estou fazendo com `JS`, existe algum `CSS` que faz isso? enfim, queria que na transição de cor, um fade fosse executado.

[EXEMPLO](http://codepen.io/furlann/pen/wBbgPj)

Comment: Já há muitas perguntas sobre isto... usa CSS transitions e dá uma classe com jQuery...

Comment: pode fazer um exemplo @Sergio ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se queres fazer um efeito de algo a piscar (com fade-in e fade-out) podes fazer assim:

CSS:

```
#pisca {
    color: #fff;
    transition: color .7s;
}
.mostrar {
    color: #f34 !important;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function pisca() {
    var $pisca = $('#pisca');
    $pisca.addClass('mostrar');
    setTimeout(function () {
        $pisca.removeClass('mostrar');
    }, 750);
}

window.onload = function () {
    setInterval(pisca, 1500);
}
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s0r82xbx/

Desta maneira não precisa o jQuery-UI e fazes a animação com CSS. Repara que o efeito de fade-in/fade-out neste exemplo é fictício pois estou a fazer mudaça de côr entre a côr do *background* (pano de fundo branco) e vermelho, dando assim a ilusão de fade.

Se quiseres fazer mudança de opacidade podes fazer assim (usando o mesmo principio de transição) [ficaria assim (jsfiddle.net/s0r82xbx/1/)](https://jsfiddle.net/s0r82xbx/1/), mas apesar o efeito é menos interessante.

Answer (score 3):

O efeito de "texto a piscar" pode ser obtido recorrendo apenas a CSS:

```css
p {
  background-color: #000;
}
.piscar {
  color: #FFF;
  -webkit-animation-name: blinker;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-name: blinker;
  -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: blinker;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@-moz-keyframes blinker {
  0% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blinker {
  0% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
}
@keyframes blinker {
  0% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="piscar">Olha lá pá, vez-me a piscar?</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tem algumas opções abaixo que você utilizando o CSS modificando a cor para branco pode contribuir.

Caso você queira modificar o estado dar cor em algum link através do comportamento do mouse, usar:

```
a:link {
    color: #;
}

/* Quando entra no no navegar carrega a tela a cor fica "00FF00" */
a:visited {
    color: #00FF00;
}

/* Quando passa o mouse por cima a cor fica rosa */
a:hover {
    color: #FF00FF;
}

/* Quando aperta o link a cor passa pra azul escuro */
a:active {
    color: #0000FF;
}
```

Você também poderá utilizar esses eventos do mouse para adicionar um *underline* em baixo da palavra :

```
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:active {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Poderá modificar o background da palavra exemplo :

```
a:link {
    background-color: #B2FF99;
}

a:visited {
    background-color: #FFFF85;
}

a:hover {
    background-color: #FF704D;
}

a:active {
    background-color: #FF704D;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usando o hover como exemplo, é possível fazer uma transição na cor facilmente usando a propriedade `transition` do CSS.

Com o simples HTML: `<span class="cor">Teste</span>`

E o CSS (Neste caso, SASS):

```
span.cor
    font-size: 30pt
    color: red
    transition: color ease-in-out 2s
    &:hover
        color: blue
        transition: color ease-in-out 2s
```

Veja que defino uma cor para o estado natural da classe, e outra para o `:hover`. A `transition` me diz que a propriedade `color` vai transicionar de maneira linear, entre as cores definidas por mim, em um tempo de `2s`. Leia mais sobre transitions [aqui](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp).

Um exemplo do funcionamento desse código pode ser visto [nesta pen](http://codepen.io/caio1511/pen/XJwPZM).